# Count occurrences of given character in interval

Tags: google-sheets, count, character

I have an interval of data that seems like this:

[image]

I need to count how many Vs and how many Ds there are.

I already tryed with `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Join all the cells
- Use Regex to replace everything other than the required character(ex.`V`) to null
- Find the length of remaining string

#### Sample Formula:

```
=LEN(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(,A2:A9),"[^V]",)))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't work for me, but helped me find the answer. +1

Comment: @David Didn't work because of your language settings. Change all `,` to `;`>It'll work

Answer (score 2):

This Formula could also help. Just edit the range and letter according to the requirement here and you will get the exact number.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(len(A$1:A)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A,"V",""))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't work for me, but helped me find the answer. +1